# Best way to deal with the same div multiple places on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, forms

I have a div that is a rather large form. Maybe 20 fields.

I use this form for creating a new user and editing an existing one. I have a user search and if you click on any result in the result list it shows this form. Point being, i use it a lot, and in multiple places.

My questions is what is the best strategy to manage this?

My first idea was to create the form and hide it when the page loaded. Then append it to where I needed it and show it. But then it got very complicated when I tried to use empty on the container that contained this form, as I would them never be able to use it again.

So I tried creating a global variable: `var MY_FORM = $("#MyForm");` And just use `.append(MY_FORM)` whenever I needed it, but this did not work.

I then thought about using `.html()` to replicate the form wherever I needed it. But this gets very complicated with replicated ids. `.button()` requires that I use a label which needs a for attribute that relies on the buttons id attribute which would be duplicated with multiple instances of the form.

My latest thought was to just create the form wherever it could possibly be needed and just show it when the time was right.

As you can see I'm quite conflicted and my head hurts and it's still 8 A.M. where I am... :-(

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

P.S. if you can think of a better title feel free to change it.

Comment: my other thought was to create the form as a JQuery UI model dialog, but now i'm changing functionality because of a technical problem, and I don't like that.

Comment: ooooo, OK. You got me interested. Never even heard of that though.

Comment: Why don't you try creating the form on the server side and load it via ajax?

Comment: I like the widget idea. Another complication with using the same div, is If I have, say an accoridan, it's very difficult to have the div on two panels of the accorddian. Say one panel is a create user, and one panel is an edit user. switching back and forth would require me moving the div. Thats quite a bit of work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution with the global variable and the append method should work (*if implemented correctly*)

**Check a demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aCnuR/

example **html**

```
<div id="place1" class="formplacer">
    <button class="getform">Bring form here</button>
</div>
<div id="place2" class="formplacer">
    <button class="getform">Bring form here</button>
</div>
<div id="place3" class="formplacer">
    <button class="getform">Bring form here</button>
</div>

<form id="multiform">
    input
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sumbit" />
</form>
```

example **jquery**

```
var myform = $('#multiform').detach();

$('.getform').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.formplacer').append(myform);
});
```

---

**UPDATE**
(*with animation and not using detach as it is not really required..*)

```
var myform = $('#multiform').hide(0);

$('.getform').click(function(){
    var base = this;
    myform.slideUp('slow', function(){
        $(base).closest('.formplacer').append(myform.slideDown('slow'));
    });
});
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aCnuR/6/

Comment: Almost exactly what I was doing, except I did not use the .detach(). Also what would be your method of hiding/removing the form?

Comment: @Gaby - http://jsfiddle.net/aCnuR/3/ - I tried to modify your solution to use .hide() and .show() to get some animation. However, the first time I click show after loading the page it's choppy. Do you know why?

Comment: @kralco626, detach it again.. [**updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aCnuR/2/) The good thing about [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) is that it maintains all data associated with the object removed. (*jquery handlers and everything*)

Comment: So maybe it didn't work when I tried it just because I didn't say .detach() when I defined the global variable.

Comment: @kralco626, not sure about the choppiness. I can see it too, but cant understand the reason..

Comment: @Gaby - ya, I could not figure it out, I have the same issue with my current solution. I was thinking about creating a simplified example and posting it as a question. Maybe I should take this example and post it as a question.

Comment: @kralco, removing the detach, but still maintaining a reference to the object works as well, and it seems to solve the choppy animation too. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aCnuR/4/

Comment: @Gaby - got rid of the choppyness, but i'm still not sure why? - http://jsfiddle.net/aCnuR/5/ - however, you will notice the hiding of the form does not work quite right. If you remove the "slow" from the hide on the onclick handler it works, but i want the animation...

Comment: @Gaby - both of our solutions have the issue with the append happening before the hiding is complete. You will notice it in your example if you remove the `0` from the `slideup` in the click handler

Comment: @Gaby - perfect, but now i don't understand why my solution didn't work... I did exactly that, you just fixed the animation :-)... I was getting the issues when I was tyring to show the form as a global variable...

Comment: @Gaby - so the choppiness def has somethign to do with .detach()... now sure why though...

Comment: @kralco, you should post you code at jsfiddle or someplace so we can see what went wrong..

Comment: @Gaby - putting together an example of why i was trying to use .empty() now, give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Gaby - http://jsfiddle.net/aCnuR/12/ - This actually worked better than it did in my program. before, after calling .empty() the form would never show again... here it does, not sure why? However the choppyness is back after clicking search.

Comment: @kralco, choppiness is back because - *like with detach* - jQuery has to insert the form from memory, and not just relocate it in the DOM..

Comment: @Gaby - OK. I'm just not sure why it was not working for me. I guess i'll try again. To solve the chopyness problem I guess I would have to hide the form, move the form, and then empty?

Comment: @kralco626, the `empty` part should be skipped altogether.. since we hide it, there is no real need to remove it from the DOM..

Answer (score 1):

### Use `jQuery.tmpl()` plugin

I use this kind of scenario all the time. I'm loading my *editor* form as a template with variable placeholders and use it for creating new entity instances as well as for editing existing ones.

I don't show/hide it even though it would work faster. But I have to admit I had no issues related to DOM creation speed etc. Nor have I observed it, nor have users reported it...

Comment: I just read the documentation, how would you suggest I use it in this situation?

Comment: I really like the idea... although I would have to update my Jquery from 1.4.2 to at least 1.4.3

Comment: @kralco626: Updating jQuery library doesn't impact existing functionality. Those are not major releases. In your situation you'd have this template and use it when needed. I display my editor form as a modal dialog over the master list. If someone would click on **update** icon/link, you'd populate it with relevant JSON data. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

One of your examples *should* have worked.

```
// Showing the form where you need it.
var the_form = $("#MyForm");
$('#container').append(the_form.css('display', 'block'));

// hiding the form
the_form.css('display', 'none');
```

If this does not work, post some code samples from the project.

**A note on Duplicate ID's:**  You mention not being able to duplicate ID's because it stops jQuery UI from properly attaching a button widget.  As a matter of fact, a duplicate ID can cause problems with javascript *all over the document*; it makes the document invalid.  If the above example doesn't work, make sure you have no duplicated ID's anywhere.

**UPDATE**

Here is a working example of how to accomplish your goal:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZqpYC/

**UPDATE**

Here it is with animation:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZqpYC/1/

Comment: I don't have any duplicate ids unless I copy the div's html. inwhich case all specified ids are duplicated because I just took the html and copied it. right? or does .html() not work the way i'm thinking?

Answer (score 0):

> But then it got very complicated when I tried to use empty on the container that contained this form, as I would them never be able to use it again.

Don't do that then?  I've used the single hidden div with good success before.

> .button() requires that I use a label which needs a for attribute that relies on the buttons id attribute

How does .button() require a label?  Can you explain?

Comment: mabye i'm using it wrong: `<input type="checkbox" id="WebProccessedchk" /><label for="WebProccessedchk">Web Approved</label>` then I say `$("#WebProccessedchk").button();` I know I could use a class and that would solve the Jquery selector problem, but the label uses "for" which looks for the id on the input? no?

Comment: Ah.  That's not anything to do with button, really.  I think you just need to avoid the for attribute: `<label><input type="checkbox" />Web Approved</label>` works fine if you have some other way of selecting the right checkbox to .button().  I never use for; the only reason to would be if the label were not adjacent to the button.

Comment: well I could just say `<label><input class="approve" type="checkbox" />Web Approved</label>` and `$(".approve").button();` i think...