# Error when trying to create Jquery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, out-of-memory

I'm not really sure what i'm doing wrong because I have done this will success before.

I have some html code being added dynamically

```
...<td><label><input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\" class=\"Activechk form-contractor-active\" />Active</label></td>"...
```

Then I execute this JQuery: `$(".Activechk").button();`

I am getting an <s>`"Out of Memory" Error`</s> `"Stack Over Flow" Error`

Does this ring any bells? Becuase i'm stumped...

Update: according to fire bug error is at line 1599 of Jquery 1.4.2

Surrounding code:

```
1594 if ( !eventHandle ) {
1595 elemData.handle = eventHandle = function() {
1596 // Handle the second event of a trigger and when
1597 // an event is called after a page has unloaded
1598 return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && !jQuery.event.triggered ?
1599 jQuery.event.handle.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
1600 undefined;
1601 };
1602 }
```

Comment: This works fine if I don't execute the `.button()` command

Comment: The length is 7... doesn't seem like enough to run out of memory...

Comment: What about `$(".Activechk").each(function(index) { alert(index); $(this).button(); });`? Don't expect it to solve the problem, but do you see several alerts then it breaks?

Comment: funny thing, i had the same idea; just without the alert. As you predicted it didn't work, but i'll add the alert in, and i'll see what happens.

Comment: I did find that I was calling the .button thing twice. I removed this issue. My error has changed from `out of memory` to `stack overflow`. I also did the test you suggested above. I get the alert with `index = 0` and then it hang for a few seconds and I get the stack overflow error.

Comment: I ran firebug and it says `too much recursion` - `jquery...min.js`

Comment: Hmm.. sounds like internal problem inside `jquery.ui.button.js` source code - any chance you can debug it with Firebug and see what line is the culprit?

Comment: This is the entirety of line 30: `d)===false)break}else for(;e<j;){if(b.apply(a[e++],d)===false)break}else if(i)for(f in a){if(b.call(a[f],f,a[f])===false)break}else for(d=a[0];e<j&&b.call(d,e,d)!==false;d=a[++e]);return a},trim:function(a){return(a||"").replace(Wa,"")},makeArray:function(a,b){b=b||[];if(a!=null)a.length==null||typeof a==="string"||c.isFunction(a)||typeof a!=="function"&&a.setInterval?ba.call(b,a):c.merge(b,a);return b},inArray:function(a,b){if(b.indexOf)return b.indexOf(a);for(var d=0,f=b.length;d<f;d++)if(b[d]=== `

Comment: Replace the file with readable format (can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.button.js?r=3869) and debug again to find the real location.

Comment: firebug actually says the error is in the Jquery.js file, not Jquery.ui.js. I'll get the un-minified version and debugg on that.

Comment: firebug says the problem is in line 1599 of Jquery 1.4.2 uncompressed. Line is : `jQuery.event.handle.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) : `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at it a little more closely and am editing this answer.

It appears that the button function needs a label with a special attribute called "for" with a value that is the same as the id of the input element which will become the button.

In the below example, I observed that the label/input relationship in your sample output was different from this Label.

The below example is based on the documentation found at: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Activechk").button();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<div id="problem">
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="Activechk form-contractor-active" />Active One</label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="Activechk form-contractor-active" />Active Two</label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="Activechk form-contractor-active" />Active Three</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="solution">
<p>Inputs can be somewhere else on the DOM but cannot be child elements of labels. The buttons appear where the labels are:</p>
<!-- input elements -->
<input id="inputSolutionOne" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="Activechk form-contractor-active" />
<input id="inputSolutionTwo" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="Activechk form-contractor-active" />
<input id="inputSolutionThree" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="Activechk form-contractor-active" />

<!-- label elements -->
<table>
    <tr><td>
<label for="inputSolutionOne">Active One</label>
    </td></tr><tr><td>
<label for="inputSolutionTwo">Active Two</label>
    </td></tr><tr><td>
<label for="inputSolutionThree">Active Three</label>
    </td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. So no error, but it didn't change the checkbox into a button either... it had no effect what-so ever.

Comment: AHHA! That crossed my mind! However I had a question that involved this a little while back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509547/best-way-to-deal-with-the-same-div-multiple-places-on-the-page and I was told that this was not necessary. I guess I misunderstood the guy. The problem that I had then, and that I now have again, is that `for` requires the `input` to have an `id`. My inputs cannot have an `id` because I am creating many of them on the page, which is why I am using the class. ideas? but deff +1

Comment: @kralco626 you can have global JS variable initialized as 1 (`var _globalCounter = 1;`) then have set ID using this counter, create proper label and increment the ID by 1 every time.

Comment: @Shadow - ugh... ya I could do that. I was kinda hoping that Jquery would have a solution that did not require the use of ids... oh well...

Comment: @kralco626 jQuery has its limits - but adding such thing is really simple IMO, and if it will solve the problem.. :)

Comment: Given the limitation of whatever is creating the HTML, then I think it would be necessary to do some DOM manipulation (for each input: add an ID attribute with a unique value; give the parent label a "for" attribute with a value of the child input; remove the input element from the parent label and insert it after the label element) and then run button().